# random "MongoError: not authorized on XXX to execute command {YYY}" with mongo 3.2

Tags: authentication, mongodb

since very recently I have random errors like these:

```
2016-06-06T18:17:55.386Z pid:2458 worker:3 MongoError: not authorized on db to execute command {...someQuery...}
2016-06-06T18:17:55.386Z pid:2458 worker:3     at Function.MongoError.create (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/a6e0bde254cbdedde6345bdf94e29e51828c5fa2.1465232211706/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.386Z pid:2458 worker:3     at queryCallback (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/a6e0bde254cbdedde6345bdf94e29e51828c5fa2.1465232211706/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:200:36)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.386Z pid:2458 worker:3     at Callbacks.emit (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/a6e0bde254cbdedde6345bdf94e29e51828c5fa2.1465232211706/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.386Z pid:2458 worker:3     at null.messageHandler (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/a6e0bde254cbdedde6345bdf94e29e51828c5fa2.1465232211706/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:397:23)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.387Z pid:2458 worker:3     at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/1/work/a6e0bde254cbdedde6345bdf94e29e51828c5fa2.1465232211706/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:302:22)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.387Z pid:2458 worker:3     at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.387Z pid:2458 worker:3     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.387Z pid:2458 worker:3     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.388Z pid:2458 worker:3     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
2016-06-06T18:17:55.388Z pid:2458 worker:3     at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
```

I'm running mongo 3.2,
using latest nodeJs mongodb driver (node-mongodb-native 2.1.21) and strongloop API framework (latest of any component & related dependency)

Auth schema is SCRAM-SHA-1 over a replicaset of 2(P/S)+1(A)

It is not a connection nor password issue. it's coming out of the blue on an existing pool of connections set up by the API framework

Is anyone experiencing something similar?

Comment: Any updates on this? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this recent node driver regression: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-726. Downgrade to 2.1.18.

Comment: Your answer isn't an answer. If your link helps answer the question you should provide useful extracts and references as the link may go away.